# the correct way to use makeHidden in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with the pagination .

everything work fine without error but the problem is when i use makeHidden with my code it change the structure of my json pagination result

this is my code

```
 $result = Job::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->paginate(5);

    $result= $result->makeHidden(['hasMessage']);
```

without the second line the result is

```
 {
    total: 1 ,
    per_page: 5,
    current_page: 1,
    last_page: 1,
    next_page_url: null,
    prev_page_url: null,
    from: 1,
    to: 1,
   data: [
      {
        id: 4,
        sid:125,
        hasMessage: true
    }
        ]
}
```

but when i use

```
$result= $result->makeHidden(['hasMessage']);
```

I got

```
   [
    {
      id: 4,
      sid:125,
    }
   ]
```

any idea please ? ? ? is it a bug or there is something wrong ? ?

> **hasMessage** is an append field not a real columns

Answer (score 17):

finally I did it with small programming trick

```
 $paginator = Job::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->paginate(5);
 $data = $paginator->makeHidden(['hasMessage']);
 $paginator->data = $data;
 return $paginator;
```

thank you

Answer (score 10):

if you want to preserve pagination data use `getCollection()`and `setCollection()` methods:

```
$paginator = Job::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->paginate(5);
$paginator->setCollection($paginator->getCollection()->makeHidden(['hasMessage']));
return $paginator;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `toArray()` in your code. It should be like:

```
$result= $result->makeHidden(['hasMessage'])->toArray();
```

Have a look at the docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

**Edit:**

I also have tried to `paginate` and it did return the changed array and it is the expected output for the `makeHidden()`.

**You could also have a look at the function:**

```
public function makeHidden($attributes)
    {
        $attributes = (array) $attributes;

        $this->visible = array_diff($this->visible, $attributes);

        $this->hidden = array_unique(array_merge($this->hidden, $attributes));

        return $this;
    }
```

As it is doing `array_merge` it distotes your json response.

Comment: unfortunately , I have the same result , the problem is not to get json or an array the problem is the structure of my whole result  change

Comment: I  had looked at your link , even in the documentation said : All other attributes will be hidden when the model is converted to an array or JSON:

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of `makeHidden()`. You could also have a look at the function.

Comment: yes right , I think there is a bug or something else  , i had use makeHidden before but this is the first time I use it with pagination , thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add my 2 pence worth. I like to not hide certain things but hide everything except certain things..

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait ModelHelpers
{

    /**
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function everythingHiddenExcept(array $attributes): self
    {
        $columns = array_merge(array_keys($this->getRelations()), array_keys($this->getAttributes()));
        $this->makeHidden(array_diff($columns, $attributes));
        
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Add this trait to the models you want use it with and then you can do the following;

```
return response()->json([
   'post' => $post->everythingHiddenExcept(['title', 'author'])
]);
```

This way if there is future development down the line (added relations or attributes) they are not returned from your endpoint.

You may also want to deal with a pagination of `posts`. For this, add the following to your app service provider;

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::macro('everythingHiddenExcept', function(array $attributes) {
            return $this->each->everythingHiddenExcept($attributes);
        });

    }
```

And then use via;

```
$posts = Post::paginate(20);

return response()->json([
    'posts' => $posts->everythingHiddenExcept([
        'title', 'author'
    ])
]);
```

Note that the above will not work if the models in the collection are not using the trait.